# How to calculate a sigmoid function without using an exp() function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working in somewhat of a limited development environment. I'm writing a neural network in Python. I don't have access to numpy and as it is I can't even import the math module. So my options are limited. I need to calculate the sigmoid function, however I'm not sure how the exp() function works under the hood. I understand exponents and that I can use code like:

```
base = .57
exp = base ** exponent
```

However I'm not sure what exponent should be? How do functions like numpy.exp() calculate the exponent? This is what I need to replicate.

Comment: Just suggesion, you can use google colab because numpy will calculate fast

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but if you cannot even import `numpy` or `math`, then your chances of creating a functional and fast neural network framework are somewhat low. I'm sure that it's an interesting learning opportunity, so good luck nonetheless!

Comment: The exponential function is e^x, I'm not really sure but you can try something like [e**x for x in range(base) where e is 2.718281828459045. According to the fact e is Euler number constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The exponential function `exp(a)` is equivalent to `e ** a`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), where [`e` is Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

```py
>>> e = 2.718281828459045
>>> def exp(a):
...    return e ** a
...
>>> import math  # accuracy test
>>> [math.exp(i) - exp(i) for i in range(1, 12, 3)]
[0.0, 7.105427357601002e-15, 2.2737367544323206e-13, 1.4551915228366852e-11]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sigmoid(z):
    e = 2.718281828459
    return 1.0/(1.0 + e**(-1.0*z))

# This is the formula for sigmoid in pure python
# where z = hypothesis. You have to find the value of hypothesis
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ** just fine for your use case it will work with both float and integer input

```
print(2**3)
8
print(2**0.5 )
1.4142135623730951
```

if you really need a drop in replacement for numpy.exp()
you can just make a function that behaves like it is written in the docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html

```
from typing import List
def not_numpy_exp(x:[List[float],float]):
    e = 2.718281828459045 # close enough
    if type(x) == list:
        return [e ** _x for _x in x]
    else:
        return e**x
```

Answer (score 0):

*how the `exp()` function works under the hood*

If you mean `math.exp` from built-in module `math` in this place it does simply

```
exp(x, /)
    Return e raised to the power of x.
```

where `e` should be understand as `math.e` (`2.718281828459045`). If `import math` is not allowed you might do

```
pow(2.718281828459045, x)
```

instead of `exp(x)`